# How do I apply AngularJS ui.bootstrap collapse to individual elements?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse seems to show how to do it for one element. What if I have multiple panels that I want to collapse / expand?

How can I trigger the expanding of one panel to collapse the others like in the actual [Bootstrap Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [UI Bootstrap Accordion](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion).